# How can I backup Linux Ubuntu 20.04 VPS to Google Drive or Windows?

Tags: server, backup, vps

I got myself a VPS and learning how to manage it myself. So you can say I'm a noob in this. So everything seems to be working perfectly but what I need right now is to backup my system to Google Drive so that I can restore it when I need it. This is because I might have to change my provider in the near future and I don't want to do all the configurations again. And also because I don't want to lose my sudo users and files.

I have been looking online and found about Timeshift. Is there a way I can back my system with Timeshift and store it in Google Drive? I don't need to do it periodically but when I want to.

Also the tutorials of setting Timeshift is made with Ubuntu GUI and I don't have a GUI. I work on my server from CLI. Is there a way I can set it up from CLI?

Also please note that I'm not aware of Timeshift is open source or not. I am looking for a free one. If you have any suggestions please go ahead and mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Timeshift is open source. It's in the Ubuntu repositories.

Yes, Timeshift can be controlled from the shell (CLI).

Google Drive --which requires OAuth-- requires a bit of additional software and an API Key to use as a backup storage device. Those hurdles were put in place by Google, not us.

A Windows system requires an SSH server. If that LAN doesn't have a consistent IP address, then a DDNS client may be useful, too. And, of course, you must port-forward the Router so Timeshift can find the PC.

Comment: Thanks so much sir for your valuable input. However, I have not understood anything in the last two paragraphs. Is there any tutorial for any one of the last two?

Comment: If you don't understand, then you are not ready to implement. More learning.

Comment: Yeah. Can you please point me to any tutorial from where I can learn?